# Why a lambda delegate declared as an instance field can only access static members?

Tags: c#, class, lambda, delegates, class-members

I have this:

```
public class Demo {

    private IService _service;
    
    Action<Guid> action = v => _service.CallServiceWithParameter(v);

}
```

I get error:

```
Cannot access non-static field '_service' in static context
```

huh? Where is the static context and why is a lambda forced to be static? the lambda itself is *not* static...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [c# Methods error CS0236](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43211580/c-sharp-methods-error-cs0236) and [CS0236 A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'corona.line'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60639734/)

Comment: I just get CS0236, as Olivier says, and that error doesn't specify "in static context" so I'm curious what specific error you're getting here.

Comment: I do think it's a bit of an overreach of the rule as the lambda is not actually _run_ at the point of definition. It is just created. And I'd have thought that to define the lambda: action you don't actually have to _run_ the lambda...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Field initializers are **static statements** that are evaluated **before the constructor is executed**, which is why they can only access other static items.

You can see this if you try to replace the initializer with a method call; it will only compile if you make that method static.

Here is a runnable Demo fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/IVtMHJ

Code from the fiddle:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Demo is going to be created");
        var d = new Demo();
        Console.WriteLine("Demo has been created");
    }
}

public class Demo
{
    public Demo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Running constructor");
    }

    private IService _service;
    
    Action<Guid> action = CreateAction();
    
    public static Action<Guid> CreateAction() // Will get compile error above if we remove "static" here
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Running CreateAction");
        return null;
    }
}

public interface IService { }
```

Output:

> Demo is going to be created
> Running CreateAction
> Running constructor
> Demo has been created

If you move the `CreateAction` call into the constructor then you can make it non-static:

```
public Demo()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Running constructor");
    action = CreateAction();
}

private IService _service;

Action<Guid> action;

public Action<Guid> CreateAction() // Now it does not need to be "static"
{
    Console.WriteLine("Running CreateAction");
    return null;
}
```

Output (from [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dkGm13)):

> Demo is going to be created
> Running constructor
> Running CreateAction
> Demo has been created

Answer (score 3):

Field initializer's cannot reference non-static members. You need to change your _service to be:

```
private static IService _service;
```

Or you could move it to the constructor.

```
public class Demo
{
    private IService _service;
    private Action<Guid> action;

    public Demo(IService service)
    {
        _service = service;
        action = v => _service.CallServiceWithParameter(v);
    }
}
```

Comment: Huh? But why does this rule also apply inside the lambda? Defining the lambda does not include running it - when it runs its not going to run in static context. Why does defining the lambda also include the actual content of the lambda?